# How to set the width of a Container based on the length of its child Text? Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am Trying to develop a chat app and I am trying to display the text messages inside a container and set the width according to the length of the message. How can I set the width according to the length of a String?
P.S messages are displayed using listview.builder and each container has a background color.

```
ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
        itemCount: messages.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            margin: index % 2 == 0
                ? EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0, right: 60.0)
                : EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0, left: 60.0),
            decoration: index % 2 == 0
                ? BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  )
                : BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  ),
            child: Text(
              messages[index].text,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

### What I want:

[image: What I want]

### What I am getting:

[image: What I am getting]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final messages = [
      'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
      'This is a short message.',
      'This is a relatively longer line of text.',
      'Hi!'
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: messages.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Flex(
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              mainAxisAlignment: index % 2 == 0
                  ? MainAxisAlignment.start
                  : MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                  ),
                  decoration: index % 2 == 0
                      ? BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      : BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[300],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                  child: Text(messages[index],
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 12):

Ok, that's because children of `ListView` always are stretched , I made some changes to your code, first use `Align` widget to align to left or right depends of the index, and wrap your `Container` with `UnconstrainedBox` to avoid filling the width.

```
  ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
        itemCount: messages.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Align(
            alignment:
                index % 2 == 0 ? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight,
            child: UnconstrainedBox(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                decoration: index % 2 == 0
                    ? BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                      )
                    : BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                child: Text(
                  messages[index].text,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
```

Comment: UnconstrainedBox did it for me