# How to determine width of Container based on string length?

Tags: flutter, pdf

I want to make a field, a bordered container to be more explicit, for printing but I want it to have the width based on what length the string should have.

For example, let's say the pdf should have a field for a code which will contain 14 characters.
How can I make the container to fit those 14 characters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the code below, it shows 2 ways -  (1) RenderBox and (2) TextPainter - to get the width of Text. You may use the method that suits you. RenderBox method can only be used after build so it is called after build using WidgetsBinding addPostFrameCallback.

Note 1: This code uses default TextStyle. If you use a different TextStyle then you will have to pass that TextStyle in the function.

Note 2: You asked only for text width, so this code shows you how to get text width. You may give the appropriate padding or margin to the containers that your draw in your PDF.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static const int _stringLength = 14;
  final GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
  Size _sizeRenderBox;
  Size _sizeTextPainter;

  Size _getSizes() {
    final RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    return renderBox.size;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _sizeRenderBox = _getSizes();
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  Size _textDetails(BuildContext context, [text = ""]) {
    final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.fontSize),
      ),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor,
    )..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
    return textPainter.size;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _sizeTextPainter = _textDetails(context, "A" * _stringLength);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Flutter Demo")),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Text("Container - "),
                  Container(
                    height: _sizeRenderBox?.height,
                    width: _sizeRenderBox?.width,
                    child: Text("A" * _stringLength),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                  "RenderBox - Height: ${_sizeRenderBox?.height} Width: ${_sizeRenderBox?.width}"),
              Text(
                  "TextPainter - Height: ${_sizeTextPainter?.height} Width: ${_sizeTextPainter?.width}"),
              Offstage(
                child: Container(
                  key: _key,
                  child: Text("A" * 14),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems excessive, just to get the length of a string and set it to the width of a container.

Answer (score -3):

Character width is (I believe) 4-5 pixels, so just get the string length * 4 and set that to the width of the container.

```
final containerWidth = double.parse(code.length);


Container(
  width: containerWidth,
),
```

Comment: What happens if fontsize is 6 or 60?

Comment: Then, you will have to follow the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875445/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-container-based-on-the-length-of-its-child-text-flutt

Comment: That code referenced by you in above line does not return the width of the text. It merely restricts the max width of the Container to 70% of device width when the text is actually set.  The width as per your code above for a string of 14 characters would be 56 or 70. While with the default font the length of 14 "A"s on Android device will be 128.  Further calculating text width with TextPainter or RenderBox is not excessive for Flutter. Flutter framework does it sometimes more than 60 times a second for the entire screen.